# Bower Install With Front End Template

Tags: angularjs, templates, laravel-5, bower-install

Hello i purchased a template this afternoon, previously what i used to do whenever i bought a template was to copy the js,image,font and css folders into my project and start using but this particular template i bought was very confusing for me.

I ended up having to install npm and use bower install to download the various packages, however this is my first time using bower install so i'm a bit confused as to what to do next.  "bower install" created a new folder inside my template folder called "bower_components".

I would like to know what i need to do next to be able to use this template to develop my app, below is a screenshot of my theme's folder structure:

[image]

I am building my app using **Laravel 5** on the **backend** and AngularJS on the front-end.

Comment: you can user Laravel elixir to grab all you necessary files and compile into one main css file and one main js file for your project

Comment: How do i use laravel elixir? Which part of the template do i copy to my laravel project and where do i put it?

Comment: All this bower and gulp and what not is soo tedious, i miss the good times when we could just copy and paste the folders. :(